# Flatten n dimensional array without concat or reduce

Tags: javascript

here I flattened a two dimensional array like the following

```js
function flatArray(a, b) {

  return a.concat(b);

}

console.log([
  ['1', '2', '3'],
  ['4', '5', '6']
].reduce(flatArray));
```

Can i do this without reduce, and concat? I can't think of a way

Comment: Sure, you loop through the arrays and combine them.

Comment: I have a solution to make var array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];, flatten into another new empty array. But i'm not sure how to keep the original array flattened, without inserting it into another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a relatively clean solution:

```js
function flatten(ar) {
  // if ar is not an array, return it in a single-element array
  if(!Array.isArray(ar)) { return [ar]; }

  // convert each element of ar to a flattened copy of itself
  var flatEls = ar.map(flatten);

  // create a new array
  var newArr = [];

  // push the contents of each array in flatEls into the new array
  flatEls.forEach(function(el) { newArr.push.apply(newArr, el); });

  // return the new array
  return newArr;
}

console.log(flatten([['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]]));
```

And without the comments:

```js
function flatten(ar) {
  if(!Array.isArray(ar)) { return [ar]; }

  var flatEls = ar.map(flatten);

  var newArr = [];

  flatEls.forEach(function(el) { newArr.push.apply(newArr, el); });

  return newArr;
}

console.log(flatten([['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]]));
```

Comment: Could you explain the ? and : syntax. I've looked them up but am confused on the usage here

Comment: It's the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). You can see `return Array.isArray(el) ? flatten(el) : [el];` as a shorthand for `if (Array.isArray(el)) { return flatten(el); } else { return [el]; }`

Answer (score 1):

A different approach, works in situ.

```js
function flatten(array) {
    var l = array.length, temp;
    while (l--) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[l])) {
            flatten(array[l]);
            temp = array[l].slice();
            temp.unshift(1);
            temp.unshift(l);
            [].splice.apply(array, temp);
        }
    }
}


var array = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]];

flatten(array);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: its [magic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)! :-)

Comment: @cresjoy :  that's for the splice method argument.... which removes one element at index `l` and add the rest of the element on there

Answer (score 0):

The most basic way to do this would be:

```
function flatten2D(arr) {
  var flatArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      flatArr.push(arr[i][j])
    }
  }

  return flatArr
}
```

Keep in mind this assumes every element in the outer array is an array. Additional typechecks can be added into the loop as need be.

Comment: Could you look at my solution and see how i can try to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this as ***@NinaScholz*** solution with slight variation by avoiding recursion.

```js
function flatten(a) {
  // iterate over array elements
  for (var i = 0,ar; i < a.length; i++) {
    // check the current element is array
    if (Array.isArray(a[i])) {
      // copy the array
      ar = a[i].slice();
      // push value at the beginning 
      //for passing ass splice arg, 1 for delete count
      ar.unshift(1);
      // push value at the beginning 
      // for passing ass splice arg, i for the index
      ar.unshift(i);
      // call splice where a as this arg and
      // copied array as param - which delete the
      // element and add the array element to parent 
      [].splice.apply(a, ar);      
      // decrement the value since we are extracted
      // the array, otherwise it will skip the first
      // element from the extracted array
      i--;
    }
  }
}

var array = [
  [['1'], '2', '3'],
  ['4', '5', ['6'],
    ['7', '8']
  ]
];

flatten(array);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This quite happily works in n dimensions, via recursion.

```
function appendToArray (array, items) {
  var item;
  var i = 0;
  var length = items.length;

  for (; i < length; i += 1) {
    item = items[i];
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      appendToArray(array, item);
    } else {
      array.push(item);
    }
  }

  return array;
}

function flatten (input) {
  return appendToArray([], input);
}


flatten([1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, [7]]], [8, 9]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/eu7Jw3X0

```
// return two-dimension array
function filler (dimension, from) {

    var content = [], i = 0, j = 0, dimension = dimension || 0; 

    while ( ( i = content.push( [] ) ) < dimension )
        while ( ( j = content[ ( i - 1 ) ].push( reflect( i, j, from ) ) ) < dimension );
    while ( ( j = content[ ( i - 1 ) ].push( reflect( i, j, from ) ) ) < dimension );

    content.unshift( content.pop() );

    function reflect( i, j, from ) {
        if ( !from )
            return i == j ? 1 : 0;
        else
            return from.pop();
    };
};
```