# Making an array flat, understanding the solution

Tags: javascript, arrays

I posted a question a few days ago about how to flatten an array without using `concat` or `reduce` and I got some great answers but I still don't fully understand the solution I received. I will try and put my understanding of each line and maybe someone can point out where my reasoning is wrong.

```
function flatten(array) {
    var l = array.length, temp;
    while (l--) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[l])) {
            flatten(array[l]);
            temp = array[l].slice();
            temp.unshift(1);
            temp.unshift(l);
            [].splice.apply(array, temp);
        }
    }
}


var array = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]];

flatten(array);

console.log(array);
```

Ok so first

```
var l = array.length, temp;
```

here l is just 2 and so our array length is 2 and `temp` is 2

```
if (Array.isArray(array[l]))
```

if our array at position `1` (since we decremented `l` by `1` in the `while` loop) is indeed an array we will execute the next part of the code

```
flatten(array[l]);
```

Here we need to keep going in case we have nested arrays within an array

```
temp = array[l].slice();
```

since slice has no parameter `temp` = `array[1]`; so now `temp = ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]]`

```
temp.unshift(1);
```

Add one to the beginning of temp. (No idea why we are doing this, and why the number one)

```
temp.unshift(l);
```

Since `l` is `1`, we are putting another `1` at the beginning of the array.

Now `temp = [1,1,'4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]`

`[].splice.apply(array, temp)`;  ok I seriously have NO clue what this line is doing. I have been reading documentation and I understand that `apply` lets us specify a value for `this` and then we can pass some parameters and a function will run ( for the example I saw), however I can't understand what the heck is the usage here. Plus splice takes out `x` amount of elements from the index `y`, so what are these indices? here `splice` has no parameters. and whats with the empty array in the beginning `[]`. Please help me understand I am trying really hard!

Comment: That solution looks quite convoluted tbh...

Comment: _"I posted a couple days ago with the same question and I got some great answers but I still dont fully understand the solution"_ - then it'd be preferable if you went and asked there, by commenting on those answers and asking the authors for clarification where needed.

Comment: I'm sure there is a better solution, but this is bugging me and i really want to understand but my brain can't just understand :(

Comment: `[].splice.apply` is a shortcut for `Array.prototype.splice.apply`, maybe that helps understand.

Comment: I wouldn't waste too much time trying to figure out this suboptimal algorithm.

Comment: @CBroe I think I have understood the question alot more since then, I have added a bunch of more text as well giving my understanding of the question, I thought it would be better to just post it again since I think I'm almost near the solution and I actually wrote my thoughts on each line of the code this time.

Comment: it was a proposal which was keeping the requirements of *"Flatten n dimensional array without concat or reduce"*.

Comment: @eclanrs can you explain what the purpose of that line is then? What does it do to the array [1,1,'4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]

Comment: @cresjoy ok, fair enough.

Comment: @cresjoy Before moving onto a new question about the answers to your first question, how about _accepting_ one of those answers first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is about this part of the code:

```
        temp.unshift(1);
        temp.unshift(l);
        [].splice.apply(array, temp);
```

Starting with the last statement, it is calling `splice` on `array`, but in a specific way. Normally you would call it like this:

```
array.splice(l, 1, temp[0], temp[1], ...)
```

... which means: at index `l` of `array`, delete 1 element, and insert `temp[0]`, `temp[1]`, ... etc. The problem is that we don't know beforehand how many elements there are in `temp`, but still need to provide as many arguments to `splice`. And we can't just pass `temp` as argument, because then `array` gets an element inserted that is an array itself, which is what you just do *not* want to do.

While in ES6 there is an easy solution for this (see below), in ES5 you can solve this by using `apply` on `splice`. That `apply` method accepts as first argument the object to apply the function on, and then an array which has all arguments that need to be passed to that function.

As the first two of those arguments have the meaning of index, and the number of elements to delete there (see above), and only then the remaining arguments represent which elements need to be inserted (those in `temp`), there is all this shifting happening: these insert the two first arguments to pass to `splice`.

Then the remaining arguments are what originally was in `temp` (before the shifting). You could say that the `shift` and `apply` statements do the following:

```
array.splice(temp[0], temp[1], temp[3], temp[4], ...)
```

Note how `temp` is playing a role for *all* the arguments now. And that is why the first two values were shifted in. It looks complicated, and although it works, it does not result in very readable code.

Now in ES6 it has become much simpler. You can now use the spread operator to kind of explode an array into different arguments, and functions can deal with that:

```
array.splice(l, 1, ...temp)
```

And since we don't need to shift anymore, we can safely do this without the variable `temp`, and directly on `array[l]`. So the complete code would look like this:

```js
function flatten(array) {
  var l = array.length;
  while (l--) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[l])) {
      flatten(array[l]);
      array.splice(l, 1, ...array[l]);
    }
  }
}


var array = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]];

flatten(array);

console.log(array);
```

Isn't that nice and simple? ;-)

Comment: You explained well, but I am really slow and still kind of confused. Ok I know in the end  [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]]  = array. And temp is [1,1,'4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]. You explained that apply is "a method that accepts as first argument the object to apply the function on, and then an array which has all arguments that need to be passed to that function.". But what does that physically mean? Its hard for me to actually understand by words :/

Comment: Below Nina said that "it removes the part ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']] form the array and insert the values '4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8'] at the same position". But how? Sorry if its a dumb question but I still dont see what physically apply does.

Comment: Heres an example of how I know how to use apply. I just don't see the relation between my apply and this one                                                                          var person = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName:'Doe',
    getFullName:function(){
    var fullname = this.firstname + '' + this.lastname;
    return fullname;
    
}
    
};


var logName = function(lang1,lang2)
{
    console.log('Logged: ' + this.firstName + "speaks " + lang1 + " "+ lang2);
}


logName.apply(person,['english','spanish']);

Comment: There are two things: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). They are two different things and do completely different things. Try not to mix them up. Maybe read the documentation on both methods I linked to, and then when you have a grips on that read my answer again.

Comment: In your example `logName.apply(person, ...)` the reason to use `apply` is that `logName` is not a method of `person`, and so you could not have done `person.logName(...)`. The `apply` method offers you a work-around for that. But `apply` can also solve another problem: when you don't know beforehand how many arguments you will pass. As `apply` can pass 1 array to a function as separate arguments, `apply` can also solve that issue. That is what is happening in the code in your question.

Comment: Ok im still a bit confused but I guess I could give it a shot and read some documentation.. Thanks for now :)

Comment: I think i understand what splice  does. It removes x amount of things from an index of y, and inserts something you want to put in, like var myFish = ['angel', 'clown', 'mandarin', 'surgeon']; then var removed = myFish.splice(2, 0, 'drum'); removes 0 things from the second index and inserts drum.

Comment: Yes, now the challenge is when you need to insert **n** elements without knowing **n** when you write the code. Let's say you don't need to remove anything, but insert at position 3 those **n** elements, then it should look like `array.splice(3, 0, value1, value2, ... valuen)`, but that is not valid syntax. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Oh your right. But what are we even trying to add? I thought we are just trying to remove those brackets to make it into one flat array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115604/discussion-between-trincot-and-cresjoy).

Answer (score 0):

I recognize the challenge from fcc .. but that's an insanely complicated way to do it. This is how is solved it.

```
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) { 
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten); 
  }, []);
}
function steamroller(arr) {
 return flatten(arr);
}

steamroller([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

The solution you posted is insanely complicated and messy and broken, the unshifts at the end simply add 1,1 to the beginning of the array, it's a dirty way to pass the challenge ...

Comment: the original requirement was [*"Flatten n dimensional array without concat or reduce"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37974031/1447675).

Comment: Not when I did it, anyway the solution you posted is not really a solution, it only works for that ONE specific case.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution, I'll research a bit into .reduce ( I have never used it much before) , and see if I understand this code. If you dont mind could you explain what [].splice.apply means however? That was what I am really concern about

Comment: @cresjoy, `[].splice.apply` has three part, one the array in front, its just an array, the second is a method of array, splice and the third is a method how to call splice. in this case apply uses the this object and an array as parameter list for the call of splice. this in in this case the array ob which splice is working on and temp is the parameter array.

Comment: so what is apply(array,temp) exactly doing? Like what does that mean because our first parameter is the WHOLE array i.e  [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]], and temp the second parameter is [1,1,'4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]. So when we use "apply", what does that do?

Comment: it removes the part `['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']]` form the array and insert the values `'4', '5', ['6'], ['7', '8']` at the same position.

Comment: So does [].apply(array,temp) do anything by itself? Lets forget splice for a second

Answer (score 0):

I would do this job like this;

```js
var a =[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', ['6'], ['7', ['8','9']]]];
Array.prototype.flat = function(){
  return this.reduce((p,c) => Array.isArray(c) ? p.concat(...c).flat() : p.concat(c),[]);
};
var b = a.flat();
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

Comment: The question is about understanding the algorithm in the question, not about finding a completely different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Splice is a function which takes the index to start at, the number of elements to remove, and 0+ elements to insert inside of the hole you left.

Apply is a method that functions have (yes, functions are objects and have methods).
It takes a `this` and then it takes an array of arguments to pass in.

When you have no idea how many elements you have, but you need to pass them all to a function:

```
// instead of
fn(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);

// you can say
fn.apply(null, args); // args being an array of arbitrary length
```

So you can then say:

```
array.splice.apply(array, args);
```

Where args should be the index, the number to remove, and then an arbitrary list of elements to put inside of that hole.

The `[]` is just a throw-away array to have quick access to `splice` (to call it with `apply`).