# Javascript Recursive Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

My goal is to write a function that will flat an array. So for example [1,[2,3]] should turn to [1,2,3]. I tried it with a recursive method as seen below, but it produces an endless loop.

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {

 var resultArray = [];

 function flatArray(array) {    
   for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
         flatArray(array[i]);
     } else resultArray.push(array[i]);
   }
 }

 flatArray(arr);         
 return resultArray;
}

steamrollArray([1, [2,3]]);
```

What is my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look into [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Also, `steamrollArray([1, [2, 3]])` produces `[1, 2, 3]` as expected.

Comment: yes, just tested, it works on Chrome

Comment: Declare your variables, `i` is global, hence every call to `flatArray` makes it start from zero.

Comment: Additionally, if you use lodash, you can take a look at [_.flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flattenDeep)

Comment: It appears to work fine with the example you give, although Nina's answer is a more conventional (and clearer) way to do recursion.

Comment: @ADyson How would it work with the global loop counter?

Comment: Ok, then it has to do something with the freecodecamp.com website

Comment: @Teemu I only said the given example works...you'd need to put `var i = 0` to make it work properly.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38032059/4543207) up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move `resultArray` inside of `flatArray` and concat the recursive call of `flatArray` to the result as well.

It is a good approach to see a recursion from the end, that means, you need an array as result, then you need to declare an array at start and return the array at last, or inbetween of the function.

While processing the data, you need to append the array with either a single item or with an array as result of a recursive call of a sub array. Both parts are in the if clause.

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
    function flatArray(array) {
        var resultArray = [], // move inside
            i;                // declare as well
        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
                resultArray = resultArray.concat(flatArray(array[i]));
                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            } else {
                resultArray.push(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return resultArray; // return result here
    }

    return flatArray(arr); // return the result of the call
}

console.log(steamrollArray([1, [2, 3]]));
console.log(steamrollArray([[1, 9, [7, 8]], [2,3]]));
```

Comment: Ok, it works fine. Can you tell my why I have to make these changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that:

```js
var yourArray = [1, [2,3,4,5], [6,7], 8, [9]];
var result = yourArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
 if( a.constructor === Array){
  return a.concat(b);
 }
 return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this doesn't work for 'deeper' arrays e.g. [1, [[[2,3],4],5]]